# Re-open previously opened tabs in Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, tabbed-browsing

I've recently converted to Safari 5 on Mac OS X SL  from Chrome 13 and was wondering whether Safari has a similar option to Google Chrome's "reopen previously closed tabs" on startup. I.e., every time I open Safari, it will open the tabs and windows that were closed at my last quit out of safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click on Setting icon on the right corner of the safari browser now select the `preferences` and then in `General` tab `Safari opens with` and change the option from A new Window to All windows from last session.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update: I found it - under `Preferences >> General >> Safari Opens With` - I set this to `All windows from previous session`- It worked!